# Can i publish Mit licensed android application(downloaded from github) on google play console?

Tags: android, google-play

I just want to publish android apps and i want a readymade source code of android projects. I am just researching it and i find many source code online but I am a little bit doubtful about publishing these source code on google play console that they will suspended in future so please guide me on how I can publish online source code so that my play console account not suspended. Is MIT licensed android apps allowed to publish on google play console? If yes what is the correct way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing terms are not related to programming.

Comment: Have you ever read that license? It should be pretty clear that one can use it for whatever commercial or non-profit project - with the condition, that the original copyright notice *must* be retained & displayed.

Comment: ok bro i know this is off topic but i cannot get proper answer .Sorry for this

Comment: the tag-wiki for tag `licensing` would already have provided hints.